# Rails children not rendering p

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, children

I have a model called Task Order that has_many Invoices. When I click "Show" for a Task Order, it is supposed to show all of the Invoices that belong to that Task Order. However, when I click "Show" it shows ALL of the invoices, even ones that do not belong to that task order. Note that I have the same relationship and views for my Contract/Task Order, but it is working correctly so I am not sure where I went wrong.

Here is my Task Order model:

```
class TaskOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :contract
has_many :invoices, :dependent => :destroy
validates_presence_of :id
validates_uniqueness_of :id
self.primary_key = :id
end
```

Here is my Invoice model

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :task_order
validates_presence_of :task_order_id
end
```

Here is my views/task_orders/show code

### Invoices:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
  <th>Invoice Date</th>
  <th>Invoice #</th>
  <th>PoP</th>
  <th>Amount</th>
  <th>Description</th>
  <th>Invoice TO</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
</tr>

   <tbody>
<% @invoices.each do |invoice| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= invoice.invoiceDate%></td>
    <td><%= invoice.invoiceNumber %></td>
    <td><%= invoice.PoP %></td>
    <td><%= number_to_currency(invoice.amount) %></td>
    <td><%= invoice.description %></td>
    <td><%= invoice.task_order_id %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', invoice %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_invoice_path(invoice) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', invoice, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?'     } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
 </tbody>

</table>
```

And here is my Task Order controller:

```
def show
  @invoices = Invoice.all
end

def index
  @task_orders = TaskOrder.all
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `show` method, you just want to get only the task order's invoices, rather than all invoices, which you are currently getting.

```
def show
  @task_order = TaskOrder.find(params[:id])
  @invoices = @task_order.invoices
end
```

This way, you don't need to change your `show.html.erb` file. In addition, you should take a look at the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/), which should aid you in your quest to learn Rails.